# Cast exception Error in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Getting the below Error when trying to assign a `string` to an `AnsiString`:

> Error 'Implicit string cast with potential data loss from 'string' to
>   'AnsiString' in Delphi XE2'

Code:

```
String1 := IntToStr(instance.CurrentSpeed);
UDPSocket1.Sendln(String1);
```

Comment: What type is `String1`?  See [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/W1058_Implicit_string_cast_with_potential_data_loss_from_'%25s'_to_'%25s'_(Delphi))

Comment: AFAIK you get a **warning** and not an **error**. Use an **explicit** cast to AnsiString to get rid of the warning. But you should know the meaning of an explicit cast: *I state that there will be no data loss or if any that will not harm the application in any way*

Comment: Why not show a [mcve] so that we don't have to guess which line is the cause, or guess what type your variables are? Why are you even working with `AnsiString`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the OP is clearly using the (deprecated)`TUdpSocket` component.  Its `Sendln()` method takes an `AnsiString` as input: `function Sendln(s: AnsiString; const eol: AnsiString = CRLF): Integer;`

Answer (score 1):

`IntToStr()` returns a `String`.  In Delphi 2009+, `String` maps to `UnicodeString`.  However, the `TUdpSocket.Sendln()` method takes an `AnsiString` instead.  Since you are passing a `UnicodeString` to `Sendln()`, a runtime conversion has to be performed, and converting Unicode data to Ansi is potentially lossy for Unicode characters > $007F.  That is what the compiler is warning you about.  The compiler cannot verify the result of such a conversion at compile-time.

To get rid of the warning, you need to use an explicit type-cast so the compiler knows you understand the risk and have accepted it (which in this case is OK, since `IntToStr()` returns only ASCII characters that are not lossy when converted to Ansi):

```
UDPSocket1.Sendln(AnsiString(String1));
```

A better solution is to stop using the `TUdpSocket` component in the first place.

1. The `Web.Win.Sockets` unit was written back in the Kylix days when Borland was trying to implement its own cross-platform socket code (before ditching the effort and adopting Indy instead). The components in this unit are not written very well.  They cater to a lowest-common-denominator approach to socket APIs across platforms, so they don't have much functionality to them. They don't do error handling very well (if at all).  They are difficult to use in general. Etc.
2. the `Web.Win.Sockets` unit was finally removed in XE6. Embarcadero doesn't support it anymore (and for good reason).

You really should stay away from the components in the `Web.Win.Sockets` unit altogether.

For instance, Indy 10 ships with Delphi.  It has a `TIdUDPClient` component that you can use instead, and it fully supports Unicode strings.  For example:

```
String1 := IntToStr(instance.CurrentSpeed);
// Send() supports an optional byte encoding when converting the string data to bytes
IdUDPClient1.Send('host', port, String1+EOL);
```

Or:

```
IdUDPClient1.Host := 'host';
IdUDPClient1.Port := port;
...
String1 := IntToStr(instance.CurrentSpeed);
// Send() supports an optional byte encoding when
// converting the string data to bytes for transmission
IdUDPClient1.Send(String1+EOL);
```